# Tap release event to do something when user release a button

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I need to do something when the user press and hold a button, and then do something when the user release that pressed button. Is there a tap release event ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp`.
For more information on relation between tap and mouse events see: [msdn: Quickstart: Touch input for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It lists MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp, MouseLeave, MouseMove, MouseEnter as the mouse events used by Windows Phone to react to touch.

Button does not Raise MouseLeftButtonDown or -Up, so for this to work you can place a Control that does, e.g. Grid

```
<Grid>
  <Button />
  <Grid 
    MouseLeftButtonDown="HandleMouseLeftButtonDown"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="HandleMouseLeftButtonUp"
    Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I just tryed it but it doesn't works for buttons. It work only for textblock.